# Among $2n$ people there are two who have an even number (including $0$) of friends in common .

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The following problem is found in a textbook.

Prove that among $2n$ people there are two who have an even number (including $0$) of friends in common.

To be more precise, in a graph with an even number of vertices, there exist two distinct vertices $x$ and $y$ with the property that the number of vertices which are adjacent to both $x$ and $y$ is an even number (including $0$).

This statement holds for $n=1, 2$. If $0$ is not allowed then the statement does not hold as is seen in a path graph. Though the matrix approach may not be of help, if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph, then the statement is equivalent to saying that $A^2$ has an even off-diagonal entry. Can anyone show me how to proceed?

Comment: What does it mean to say that Sam and Joe "have the **same** number of common friends"? Isn't that **always** going to be tree? So what you're asking for is two people who have an even number of common friends?

Comment: I think that by "line graph" you mean [path graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) and **not** [line graph]((https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph). Is that right?

Comment: Yes I meant a path graph.

Comment: I don't know if this helps any, but it's easy to see that a counterexample must be a Eulerian graph, i.e., connected and each vertex has even degree.

Comment: What textbook did you find that exercise in?

Comment: Nice question. It would be clearer if you said "two who have an even number of friends in common".

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h514105 or http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h152090 or http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h68109 or http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h83868

Comment: Thanx Tad!!! Plenty of nice solutions!(especially Darij's solution.)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by contradiction. Assume all vertices in a graph $H$ have different degrees. This means that $d(v_1)=0,  \ d(v_{2n}) = 2n-1$. This is a contradiction, hence $H$ can't exist.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have witten "common friends" rather than "friends".